# VideoJs and React, events get called twice when src changes

Tags: reactjs, events, next.js, html5-video, video.js

> MyComponent.js

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
//All necessary states and codes

  return (
    <>
        <div className="w-[62.5rem] mt-4 2xl:w-[45rem] xl:w-full">
            {selectedVideo?.video_id != null && pullZoneInfo?.pullZoneurl != "" ?
                <>
                  <CourseVideoViewer
                  video_id={selectedVideo?.video_id}
                  pullZoneURL={pullZoneInfo.pullZoneurl}
                  endCurrentVideo={endCurrentVideo}
                  updateCurrerntTime={updateCurrerntTime}
                  />
              </> :
              (<Image
                  src={courseThumbnailBlob ? courseThumbnailBlob : "/image/stu-course.jpg"}
                  width={1920}
                  height={1080}
                  layout="responsive"
                  objectFit="cover"
                  className=""
                  priority={true}
              />)}
      </>
  ) 
}
```

> CourseVideoViewer.js

```js
import VideoJS from '@/components/VideoJs'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

const CourseVideoViewer = (props) => {
  const { setOpen, video_id, pullZoneURL, endCurrentVideo, updateCurrerntTime, options } = props
  const playerRef = useRef(null)
  const [srcUrl, setSrcUrl] = useState(`https://${pullZoneURL}/${video_id}/playlist.m3u8`)
  const [videoJsOptions, setVideoJsOptions] = useState({
    autoplay: false,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    html5: {
      vhs: {
        overrideNative: true,
      },
    },
    playbackRates: [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2],
    seekButtons: {
      forward: 5,
      back: 5,
    },
    muted: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [
      {
        src: srcUrl,
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
      },
    ],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setSrcUrl(`https://${pullZoneURL}/${video_id}/playlist.m3u8`)
  }, [video_id, pullZoneURL]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (srcUrl !== '') {
      setVideoJsOptions(prevOptions => ({
        ...prevOptions,
        sources: [
          {
            src: srcUrl,
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
          },
        ],
      }));
    }
  }, [srcUrl]);

  const handlePlayerReady = player => {
    playerRef.current = player

    const onPauseFunction = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
      // player?.log("video paused")

      if (typeof updateCurrerntTime === "function") {
        if (player?.currentTime() < player?.duration()) {
          updateCurrerntTime(player?.currentTime());
        }
      }
    }

    const onEndedFunction = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
      player?.log("video ended " + video_id)
      if (typeof endCurrentVideo === 'function') {
        endCurrentVideo(player?.currentTime())
      }
    }

    player.on('waiting', () => {
      // player?.log("Player is waiting")
    })

    player.on('dispose', () => {
      player?.log("Player will dispose")
    })

    player.on("ended", onEndedFunction)
    player.on("pause", onPauseFunction)

    // player.on('timeupdate', (e) => {
    //   updateCurrerntTime(player?.currentTime())
    // })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center w-full items-center">
        {srcUrl != "" ? (
          <VideoJS options={videoJsOptions} onReady={handlePlayerReady} />) : ""
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default CourseVideoViewer
```

> VideoJs.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import videojs from 'video.js'
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css'
import _ from "videojs-contrib-quality-levels";
import qualitySelector from "videojs-hls-quality-selector";

export const VideoJS = (props) => {
  const { options, onReady } = props
  const videoRef = useRef(null)
  const playerRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      console.log("to Create new vjs");
      if (!videoRef.current) {
        console.log("not creating a new vjs");
        return
      }

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoRef.current, options, () => {
        // videojs?.log('player is ready')
        if (typeof onReady == 'function') {
          onReady(player)
        }
      })

      player.hlsQualitySelector({ displayCurrentQuality: true, });


      // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
      // on prop change, for example:
    } else {
      console.log("vjs src changed");
      const player = playerRef.current

      player.src(options.sources)
      onReady(player)
    }
  }, [options?.sources[0]?.src, videoRef])

  // Dispose the Video.js player when the functional component unmounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        console.log("will dispose vjs");
        player.dispose()
        playerRef.current = null
      }
    }
  }, [playerRef])

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={videoRef} className='video-js vjs-big-play-centered' />
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoJS
```

When I am selecting a video in MyComponent the `video_id` changes, which should re-render CourseVideoViewer, in that component the `videoJsOptions` state is updated wth a new src based on the new `video_id`.

The videos play fine. I select the a video, the video is played, then I select another video, the video is played, but the problem is in the events being triggered.

`paused`, and `ended` are two events which are added to the  `player` instance in CourseVideoViewer.
Based on HTML5 Video, the events are fired, but to my surprise, even when the second video is selected, the `ended` and `paused` event for the first video is triggered.
As I keep changing the src by selecting more and more videos, the previously selected videos are seen to be triggering events attached. Like, `ended` and `paused` are triggered for each and all the videos selected so far. This is confirmed by console.logging the video_id for which the event is being triggered.
Why is this happening? What changes and additions in the code are necessary.

Videojs components example taken and modified from:
https://videojs.com/guides/react/